# How to add values by column into a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `Dataframe` with three columns `store, hour, count`. The problem I'm facing is some `hours` are missing for some `stores` and I want them to be `0`.

This is how the `dataframe` looks like

```
#     store_id   hour   count
# 0         13      0      56
# 1         13      1      78
# 2         13      2      53
# 3         23     13      14
# 4         23     14      13
```

As you can see for the `store` with id 13 doesn't have values for hours 3-23, similarly with store 23 it doesn't have values for many other hours.

I tried to solve this by creating a temporal dataframe with two columns `id` and `count` and performing a `right outer join`, but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If typo and no duplicates in `hour` per groups, solution is [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['store_id','hour'])
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index.levels[0], range(23)], names=df.index.names)
df = df.reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

---

```
print (df)
    store_id  hour  count
0         13     0     56
1         13     1     78
2         13     2     53
3         13     3      0
4         13     4      0
5         13     5      0
6         13     6      0
7         13     7      0
8         13     8      0
9         13     9      0
10        13    10      0
11        13    11      0
12        13    12      0
13        13    13      0
14        13    14      0
15        13    15      0
16        13    16      0
17        13    17      0
18        13    18      0
19        13    19      0
20        13    20      0
21        13    21      0
22        13    22      0
23        23     0      0
24        23     1      0
25        23     2      0
26        23     3      0
27        23     4      0
28        23     5      0
29        23     6      0
30        23     7      0
31        23     8      0
32        23     9      0
33        23    10      0
34        23    11      0
35        23    12      0
36        23    13     14
37        23    14      0
38        23    15      0
39        23    16      0
40        23    17      0
41        23    18      0
42        23    19      0
43        23    20      0
44        23    21      0
45        23    22      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
all_hours = set(range(24))
for sid in set(df['store_id']):
    misshours = list(all_hours - set(df['hour'][df['store_id'] == sid]))
    nmiss = len(misshours)
    df = pandas.concat([df, DataFrame({'store_id': nmiss * [sid], misshours, 'count': nmiss * [0]})])
```